Hot water pressure won’t come back. Cold water is fine
So I had to remove the cartridge from my shower. I shut off the main valve on top the water heater but couldn’t figure out why it didn’t stop the cold water. I eventually had to go outside and open the street cover to shut off all the water. I did repairs, turned the street valve back to ON but now I have no HOT water. I don’t know if the big leak I sprung in the shower emptied the tank?

If electric tank, did you turn off the power first.  The elements that heat up the water will burn up if not in water.  The valve on the tank is leaking/broken and should be replaced.

I have a gas heater. I know I have replace the valve but is there a way to get hot water back right now?

Also, I noticed when I turn on cold and hot in one sink it increases the hot pressure in the other sink. ?

Depending on the size of the tank, it will take a few hours to get the water hot again if the gas is working.  The valve on top might not be opening fully either, depending if just leaking past the seal or something is broken in it.

Before bed I relit the pilot by pressing the ignite button 90 seconds like it says and it relit fine, I thought. This morning still no HOT. I just noticed my water heat was blinking but it was totally silent. I just turned the nob to VERY HOT and pressed it and now it’s making noises heating up I assume. But it stops after about a minute or two.

I can still feel that the pipe on top the water heater is hot though. I’m confused here and can’t afford a plumber. Think it’s time to call the landlord ughh

Any last ideas?
